# How to hide links within texts in comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

How to parse  & hide links in texts in comments like [my profile](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile) .Right now i can only do  this much: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile.

It is easy to do so in questions or answers but how to do it in comments as well?

Comment: You have posted your profile page in both the links. Is it intended? The question should be made clearer. I couldn't guess, what you are asking.

Comment: Yes that was intended.I used my profile page as a sample link.In comments i am unable to hide links in texts like i did in this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments on any Stack Exchange site, use a subset of the original [markdown rules](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help), which is called as [Mini Markdown](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

The general format, if you want to hide the link in your comment,  is:

```
[Description](http://link)
```

The [Anchor text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_text) of the link goes with the square brackets and the link goes into the parenthesis.

Hence below link:

> https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile

will look like:

> [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile).

This technique can be used in the answers as well.

Another useful trick is to provide a title text for your links. This can be done using the following format.

```
[Description](http://link "<title>")
```

Hence, when you hover over the following

> [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile).

You will notice a small pop up text, that reads "Profile of Rickross". This may not be compatible with all mobile browsers though.

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted.Thanks.

Comment: You can add [this link](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which may be useful.

Comment: You can even use markdown to make links like [these](http://www.example.com "this is a nice example of how to use markdown") which provide a title text when you hover your pointer on the link.

Comment: I can't edit your post, I don't have the required reputation. The markdown for it is, `[The link text](://link/to/post "The title text")`. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is old thread but for the trivial information.

There is a help button below the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button which opens the comment editing markdown help div.

[image]

Which have the short editing manual for commenting.

Comment: Thanks a lot..this is easiest method actually..no need to memorise anything at all..

Comment: @Rickross glad could help, but as a active user it will be good if you memorize them. :)

Comment: Yes,now i can do it from memory...